# Template engine for image generation

Tags: java, image, template-engine

Does anyone know of any templating engines for generating images, preferably Java-based?

What I have in mind is something like [StringTemplate](http://stringtemplate.org) where a you have a set of parameterized templates that render to an image (or SVG, etc) rather than text.  It needs to be more general purpose than "insert text here to generate a sign". Primitives would be various shapes, other images, text, etc.

I realize I can build this pretty easily myself with a text template engine that generates SVG, but I'm looking for something that works "out of the box".

Thanks!

To elaborate a bit, here's some totally made up syntax for what I'm looking for. Image I want to generate an icon with some status overlays (like icons in Eclipse):

```
iconTemplate(base, status, svn) {
    image($base), // the base icon
    // create a 2x2 grid for status overlays
    gridlayout(2, 2) {
        // conditionally add overlays in corners based on parameters
        if($status == "error") {
            image("error.png") {
                layoutInfo : cell(1, 0)
            }
        }
        if($svn == "changed") {
            image("changed.png") {
                layoutInfo : cell(1, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note this syntax is completed made up and obviously sucks, but maybe it gets the idea across :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your needs, but how about creating a JPanel (you can use layouts, labels, other shapes ...) and save it as an image?

[Here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173336&start=0) you can find information about how to save a JPanel as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for but maybe something like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), [Grappa](http://www.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/) or [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) could help?

Comment: Although they're all cool, they're more for rendering graphs. I'm looking for more general image composition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jasper Report](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial) to generate images from templates. It have IDE to simplify templating process.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Just a link won't be much helpful, Once if the link is revoked your answer turns useless